# ¿"Huérfilo" como palabra para definir a progenitores que han perdido a sus hijos?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, neologismos

> *Si se te muere tu pareja, eres viuda o viudo; si se te muere alguno de tus progenitores eres huérfano o huérfana. ¿Pero cómo llamamos a los padres y madres a los que se les muere un hijo?*
>
> *La Federación Española de Padres de Niños con Cáncer le ha pedido a la Real Academia Española que acepte el término '**huérfilo**'.*
>
> <sub>[Artículo de El Mundo](http://www.elmundo.es/papel/historias/2017/11/18/5a0eed3ae2704e35418b4572.html) fechado el 18/11/2017.</sub>

Según la RAE, la palabra **huérfano** define, tanto al hijo que ha perdido a sus padres, como a los padres que han perdido a sus hijos:

> **[huérfano, na](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KlM0Mgt)**
>   Del lat. tardío *orphănus*, y este del gr. ὀρφανός *orphanós*.
>
> 1. adj. Dicho de una persona menor de edad: A quien se le han muerto el padre y la madre o uno de los dos. U. t. c. s.
>   **2. adj. poét. Dicho de una persona: A quien se le han muerto los hijos.**

Es cierto que esa acepción la marca como de uso poético, pero ahí está. Y consultando Wiktionary, veo que [la raíz griega](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BD%80%CF%81%CF%86%CE%B1%CE%BD%CF%8C%CF%82) también incluye ese significado.

Pero bueno... Entiendo el deseo de los padres de disponer de una palabra más específica.

Sin embargo, el término propuesto: *"huérfilo"*, en mi opinión, deja mucho que desear.
Parece un intento de mezclar "huérfano" con *filius* (hijo) o con *philos* (amor fraternal), pero sin saber bien lo que se está haciendo; en la línea de otras ocurrencias como "homofobia" o "vigorexia".
De hecho, si llego a encontrarme la palabra *"huérfilo"* sin haber leído antes el artículo, habría pensado que significaba "persona que le gustan los huérfanos"...

Lanzo pues la pregunta al stack: sin contar "huérfano", **¿qué palabra podría usarse para definir a los padres y madres que han perdido a sus hijos?**
También valen neologismos razonados y razonables.

Comment: Coincidencialmente hace unos 3 días estaba pensando en hacer la pregunta acerca de si existía esta palabra. Cuando hice mi búsqueda previa encontré que el término simplemente no existía, pero no se me ocurrió preguntar por propuestas.

Comment: Ojo. En latín el genitivo (complemento del nombre) va antes del sustantivo. Creo que en este caso debería ser _filii orfanus_ (huérfano de hijos) o _filli orbus_ (privado de hijos), con lo que se soluciona la confusión con _filos_, quedando "filiorfo". No estoy para nada seguro de lo que estoy diciendo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es un [*vacío semántico*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intervalo_sem%C3%A1ntico), y parece que existe porque durante la mayor parte de la historia humana casi todos los padres habrían perdido algunos de sus hijos, y por eso no había necesidad para tal concepto.<sup>2</sup>

No obstante, podemos intentar construir un análogo a *huérfano*:

- `Griego antiguo` ὀρφανός (*orphanós*, "sin padres")

  - `Latín tardío` *orphanus*

    - `Castellano` *huérfano*

#### 1. Del antónimo de ὀρφανός

En el griego antiguo hay tres conceptos similares en contraste con *huérfano*:

- άτεκνος (*áteknos* "sin hijos; estéril")
- άκληρος (*ákliros* "sin hijos; sin heredero")
- ακληρονόμητος (*aklironómitos* "sin heredero (término legal)")

Áτεκνος (*estéril*) no tiene la correcta significación, y ακληρονόμητος es demasiado formal. Por eso, parece que el siguiente proceso podría haber sido posible:

- `Griego antiguo` άκληρος (*ákliros* "sin hijos; sin heredero")

  - `Latín tardío` **aclirus*

    - `Latín vulgar` **ácliru*

      - `Castellano` ****ácliro*** (/ **ácrilo*) (metathesis)<sup>1</sup>

#### 2. De la palabra latina para *"sin hijos"*

La palabra latina para *"sin hijos"* era [*dēstitūtus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/destitutus). Esta palabra no tiene ningún descendiente sustantivo en castellano relacionado con esta definición (pero sí existen las palabras *destituir, destitución*, etc., relacionadas con su otra significación: *"indigente"*).

Siguiendo la formación de las palabras:

- *īnstitūtus* > *instituto*
- *prōstitutus* > *prostituto*
- *substitutus* > *sustituto*

Podría ser una forma:

- *dēstitūtus* > ****destituto***

---

<sup>1. https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/26564/20700</sup>
<sup>2. Una frase sí existe en alemán:</sup>
 <sup>• https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verwaiste_Eltern</sup>
 <sup>• https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-language-that-has-a-word-for-parent-that-lost-a-child</sup>