# ¿Cómo está formada la palabra "trabajólico"?

Tags: etimología, sufijos, neologismos

La reciente pregunta sobre el uso de [“Huérfilo” como palabra para definir a progenitores que han perdido a sus hijos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23258/5481) me hizo pensar en cómo a veces creamos palabras nuevas en base al significado de otras ya existentes, usando más un criterio de asociación o semejanza que uno "etimológico".

En concreto, me preguntaba de dónde ha salido la `L` de "trabajó**l**ico". Un "trabajólico" es una persona adicta al trabajo. En el DRAE

> [trabajólico, ca](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aBv0BxF)
>
> 1. adj. Chile <sup>1</sup>. Que trabaja afanosa y compulsivamente. U. t. c. s.

Y supongo que hemos creado esta palabra por semejanza a [alcohólico](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1e70kUE), que en su cuarta acepción es una persona que sufre [alcoholismo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1eFfesR) (problema ocasionado por el abuso de bebidas alcohólicas).

Es decir, si el alcohólico tiene un problema con el alcohol, el trabajólico lo tiene con el trabajo.

Pero, ¿de dónde sale la "L" de `trabajólico`? ¿Nos la traemos de `alcohólico`, que la lleva por supuesto por ser la letra final de `alcohol`? ¿O existe acaso una partícula "-**l**ico" con el significado de "conducta negativa asociada a X"?

---

<sub>1. Curioso que sea un chilenismo. Estaba convencido de que esta palabra estaba aceptada en el "español neutral"</sub>

Comment: Voy a añadir "trabajólico" a la lista de palabras que jamás habría esperado encontrarme en el diccionario, junto a "bebestible".

Comment: Ya en serio, en inglés se usa el término "workaholic", mezcla de "work" y "alcoholic". Me imagino que su traducción al español simplemente trata de hacer la misma mezcla, de ahí que parezca que hay un sufijo "-ólico" inventado.

Comment: @Charlie *bebestible* se usa bastante en Chile.

Comment: Tuve una profesora que llamaba a estas formas _palabras centauro_ o _palabras maleta_. Siempre creí que se trataba de un concepto lingüístico conocido, pero ahora no he podido encontrarlas en ninguna parte.

Comment: @Rodrigo: En *A través del espejo y lo que Alicia encontró allí*, Humpty Dumpty las llama *sobretodo*. Por ejmeplo: "- Bueno, verás: «agiliscosos» quiere decir «ágil y viscoso», ¿comprendes? es como si se tratara de un sobretodo…, son dos significados que envuelven a la misma palabra."

Answer (score 7):

Pienso que el término  es un calco del término workaholic:

> [**workaholic (n.)**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/workaholic)
>
> 1968, coined from work (n.) with second element abstracted absurdly from alcoholic. This sets up the old Rodney Dangerfield joke: "My old man was a workaholic: every time he thought about work, he got drunk."

Como se explica allí, la palabra es acuñada de una forma absurda (yo diría jocosa) tomando como base la palabra alcohólico.

Con esto, concuerdo con que simplemente se unió "trabajo" con "alcohólico". No encontré referencias de "lico" como un sufijo para denotar "conducta negativa".

[**Fundéu**](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/workaholic-adicto-al-trabajo-trabajoadicto-laboradicto/)  también explica algo al respecto:

> *Workaholic* puede traducirse como ‘adicto al trabajo’, y las voces **trabajoadicto** y laboradicto, que se inscriben en el paradigma de términos ya asentados en español, como drogadicto o sexoadicto, constituyen alternativas plenamente recomendables. Otras opciones, como el calco **trabajólico**, resultan menos transparentes y, por tanto, menos adecuadas.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con @Mauricio_Martinez, Diego, recuerda que la influencia del inglés en Chile es muy fuerte, además de lo copiones y siúticos que somos los chilenos, cuando se dice una palabra que proviene del inglés en Chile, todos la intentan pronunciar lo más gringo posible....

Comment: Lo mismo (alco[holic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-holic) > [workaholic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/workaholic), [chocoholic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chocoholic) etc) pasó en inglés con el sufijo -wegian de [*Norwegian*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Norwegian) (`Medieval Latin` *Norvegia* + *-ian*) > *Galwegian* (*Galway* +‎ *-ian* via *Norwegian*) > [*Glaswegian*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Glaswegian) (*Glasgow*, via *Galwegian*)

Answer (score 4):

La raíz viene del sufijo en ingles "Holic" que puede ser traducido como "fanático", o "compulsivo"  y su uso esta presente en muchas palabras en el idioma inglés, tanto que ha permeado el español en palabras como alcohólico

> [-aholic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/-aholic)
>
> suffix: -aholic; suffix: -oholic
>
> Denoting a person addicted to something.
>
> Ejemplo: "shopaholic"