# Word meaning "every two days"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, tiempo

Is there a word in Spanish which means "every two days"? If not, is there one which means "a period of two days" or "related to a period of two days"? By analogy to *dial/diario*, ..., *triduano, cuatriduano*.

There appear to be words referring to most other 'major' periods of time:

```
        |    1/3     |    1/2    |     1     |     2     |     3      |      4        |     5      |     6     |      7       | ... |     12     | ... |    15      | ... | 19 
| DAY   |            |           | dial      | ...       | triduano   | cuatriduano   | ...        | ...       | hebdomadario | ... | duodenario | ... | quincenal  | ... | decemnovenal |
| WEEK  | trisemanal | bisemanal | semanal   | bisemanal | trisemanal | ...           | ...        | ...       | ...          | ... | ...        | ... | ...        |
| MONTH | trimensual | bimensual | mensual   | bimestral | trimestral | cuatrimestral | ...        | semestral | ...          | ... | ...        | ... | ...        |
| YEAR  |            | bianual   | anual     | bienal    | trienal    | cuatrienal    | quinquenal | sexenal   | ...          | ... | ...        | ... | quindenial |
| DECADE|            |           | decenal   | vicenal   | tricenal   | cuadricenal   | ...        | ...       | ...          | ... | ...        | ... | ...        |
```

If not, this appears to be a [semantic gap](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23258/18348) in English as well, as the term for this is the phrase ['every other day'](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/22318/272638).

Comment: You're looking for a single word, I take it? Could you include a sample sentence showing where the word you're seeking would go?

Comment: Puede sonar muy básico, pero *día de por medio* es usado en Colombia, el DLE lo toma como Americanismo *día por medio* con significado *un día si y otro no*

Comment: Note that "triduano" is an adjective describing something that last a period of three days, not something that happens every three days. The same goes for "cuatriduano", but "hebdomadario" indeed means "once every seven days". Maybe from "triduano" we can create "triduanal".

Comment: *dial* y *diario* no son o mismo. *Dial* es algo relativo al día, no que ocurre todos los días

Comment: It makes me think about the Linguistics Club XKCD → https://xkcd.com/1602/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No consigo encontrar ninguna palabra que por sí sola signifique lo que pides (y me parece raro, la verdad). Así que propondré algunas expresiones que aparecen en el DLE:

> **[un día sí y otro no](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DcsVyE1#BCMJX7G)**
>
> 1. loc. adv. En días alternos.

Esta se puede reducir diciendo *día sí, día no*. Por supuesto, también puedes usar la propia definición: ***en días alternos***.

> **[cada tercer día](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DcsVyE1#BA3ZPtC)**
>
> 1. loc. adv. **un día sí y otro no**.

La siguiente es específica de América:

> **[día por medio](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DcsVyE1#BAhLhWm)**
>
> 1. loc. adv. Am. **un día sí y otro no**.

Comment: Creo que también sería valido `cada dos días`, no?

Answer (score 1):

*Every other day* tiene traducción completa en la expresión "día de por medio", o en "un día y otro no", o hasta "días alternos".

Según parece, se podría formar la palabra bidial con el sentido que quieres expresar.