# Término para referirse a una persona que no es padre

Tags: solicitud-de-término, parentesco

¿Existe un término para referirse a las personas que no son padres? (Sin tener que decir *no es padre*.)

De una persona podemos decir:

- soltera
- casada
- divorciada
- padre

**¿Existe algún término específico para hablar de una persona (casada o no casada) que no tiene hijos?**

Comment: Después de repasarme páginas y páginas del DIRAE, lo más que he encontrado es "[deshijado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=D45BsEi)" para referirse a alguien que ha sido privado de sus hijos.

Comment: inventemosla: InFili, nonFili,

Comment: He preguntado lo mismo [en el sitio de inglés](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/463236/280768), a ver qué nos dicen allí. Ya por curiosidad.

Comment: @crows are you sure that a woman who has carried the foetus to a viable term can still count as parity=0 if the birth is by Caesarean? I think stillbirths also increase your parity if after a certain gestation.as well.

Comment: @Charlie No entiendo la pregunta ni en espanhol ni en inglés. Una persona sin hijos es una persona sin hijos. ¿Porqué habría un término para eso? Una persona tiene o no tiene hijos. sin or con hijos. **una persona sin descendentes**

Comment: Relacionado [¿“Huérfilo” como palabra para definir a progenitores que han perdido a sus hijos?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23258/5481) Donde **ukemi** aporta la interesante reflexión: `Es un vacío semántico, y parece que existe porque durante la mayor parte de la historia humana casi todos los padres habrían perdido algunos de sus hijos, y por eso no había necesidad para tal concepto.` Posiblemente tengamos un vacío semántico en este caso también (todos partimos del punto de no tener hijos... hasta que los tenemos y entonces nos convertimos en padres)

Comment: @crows Él acaba de decir y yo acabo de ver su pregunta en el sitio de inglés.Por lo tanto, lo estaba comentando.  A person without children has no descendents, in Spanish and in English. a childless person, without descendants, una persona sin hijos, sin descendentes. Esto se puede decir de tales personas.

Answer (score 3):

Por lo que estoy viendo en el CORDE, la expresión más común es decir sencillamente ***sin hijos***. A continuación algunos ejemplos:

> - *Sebastián Miranda es viudo, sin hijos.* (1952)
> - *Los Herrera, un matrimonio joven, sin hijos [...].* (1951)
> - *[...] tengo una tía que no me la merezco, más buena que los ángeles, viuda sin hijos, y que me quiere como á tal [...].* (1892)
> - *y con esto se debe contentar la muger, y con la esperanza de succeder al marido en la segunda vida de la Encomienda, si acaso muriere sin hijos.* (1648)
> - *Bernaldino Vázquez de Tapia es uno de los más ricos hombres que hay en México, y sin hijos* [...]. (1547)
> - *[...] et si muriere sin fijos, que las aya el mas propinco pariente que las non oviere.* (1264)

Answer (score 0):

En Chile, se acostumbra decir:

> —Es un hombre solo.
>   —Es una mujer sola.
>   —Es una persona sola.

Nótese que, sin embargo, no lo entendemos con la connotación de *estar sin compañía porque nadie quiere estar con la persona*.

Desconozco si esto se usa en otros lados, pero, al menos, coloquialmente, así es como lo usamos.

Comment: La pregunta habla de referirse a una persona "sin hijos" pero no necesariamente "sin pareja". Si digo "es un hombre solo" entiendo que además de sin hijos está sin pareja. ¿Se entiende así en Chile?

Comment: @Charlie Es complicado; puede entenderse de las dos formas. Es por esto que debe haber contexto para poder entender a qué se refiere.